# Drawstring word wrap or display entire text

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0

This is the output i get when i use DrawString.

> I=Smith,John II=Johnson,Mark III=Anderson,James IV=William,Craig
>   V=Ford,He...

page is a float datatype which value is based on e.PageSettings.Margins.Left;

e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8F, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, page, 30);

In the above example, it is

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8F, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, page, 30);
```

I tried using this

```
StringFormat format = new StringFormat();            
format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.FitBlackBox;

 e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8F, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, page, 30, format);
```

How do i expand/word wrap so that i can have the entire words instead of '...' at the end?

> I=Smith,John II=Johnson,Mark III=Anderson,James IV=William,Craig
>   V=Ford,Henry

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can "word wrap" the text by using a bounding rectangle.

Use [Graphics.DrawString Method (String, Font, Brush, RectangleF, StringFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327574%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The RectangleF specifies the draw area and it will automatically "wrap" your text for you.

Comment: I used the above example, still i get '...' in the end.

Comment: What are the boundaries of your drawing rectangle?

Comment: Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 80, 800, 20);

Comment: 800 pixels wide? I assume that your window will be at least 900 pixels wide? It's also only 20 pixels high, I doubt that the text would even "wrap" with that height.

Comment: is there possibility to : "word wrap" the text by using a bounding CIRCLE ?