# Generating tiff file from a multi-line text box in C#

Tags: c#, tiff

I am writing info entered on a web form into a tiff file. My issue is where the comment box comes into play for the web form. The comment box is multi-line and when writing it on to the tiff file, some of the information entered into the comment box falls out of the tiff image.

The code for how I am trying to write it to the tiff file:-

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(800, 1000); //Creates Bitmap
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
g.DrawString("Comment: " + CommentBox.Text, outputFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 700)); // Writing the text from the comment box on to the Tiff file.
```

so what that means to me is, if I am writing a multi line comment as:-

"Hello Testing.

Hello Testing again and again and again  and again  and again and again and again.

Hello Testing again and again and again  and again  and again and again and again. Hello Testing again and again and again  and again  and again and again and again."

My tiff-file captures line elements only upto the 1000 width, the elements beyond that width do not automatically get generated in a new line.

Can anyone help me with this? ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawstring word wrap or display entire text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507842/drawstring-word-wrap-or-display-entire-text)

Comment: will CommentBox.DrawToBitmap(...) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this - you can use the overload of DrawString that takes a containing rectangle, and the text should wrap within that:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(800, 1000); //Creates Bitmap
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
   RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(new PointF(0, 700), new SizeF(200,200)); // adjust these accordingly for your bounding rect
   StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
   drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
   g.DrawString("Comment: " + CommentBox.Text, outputFont, Brushes.Black, rect, drawFormat); // Writing the text from the comment box on to the Tiff file.
}
```

Comment: what does the values in new SizeF(200,200) signify ? 

and thank you! it works.

Comment: The SizeF(200,200) specifies that the RectangleF has both sides 200 pixels long.