# Graphics DrawString word wrap

Tags: c#

I have such model of image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulLTS.jpg

I need to print text in the yellow box.

The problem is how to enable word wrap in graphics DrawString?
My code:

```
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
    {
        Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        g.DrawString("test text; test text;test text;test text", drawFont, drawBrush, new Point(240, 250));
    }
    pictureBox1.Image.Save("Image.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

text that I print overflows

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a `DrawString` overload that takes a `Rectangle` this will wrap text to that boundary

Comment: Helps if you think it through for a bit, it of course cannot wrap anything if you don't tell it how wide the text is allowed to be.  Only use Graphics.DrawString() on high resolution devices/images, you typically should be using TextRenderer.DrawText() and TextFormatFlags.WordBreak.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9507842/1997232) asked earlier (to link them, not sure if it's worth to mark as duplicate or merge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DrawString` method has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sb1bw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where you can pass in the bounding box the text has to fit in.

Your code should look something like this:

```
       g.DrawString("test text; test text;test text;test text", drawFont, drawBrush, new RectangleF(240f, 250f, endPointX, endPointY));
```

Comment: It will cut the text which exiting the point,but not wrapping the text into next line