# How to get text to fit in printPreviewDialog Document C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, print-preview

I am trying to get a long description to fit into my printPreviewDialog Document. However, when I type the description in my text box and try to print it the text does not stay on the document. [Text not staying on document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv6AC.png) The line of code that is causing this issue is the last one 
`e.Graphics.DrawString("Description:" + description4Repair.Text, new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(50, 493));`

All code:

```
       e.Graphics.DrawString("DEVICE INFORMATION:", new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(286, 373));


        e.Graphics.DrawString("Device Type:" + devices.Text, new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(50, 403));

        if (devices.Visible == true & devices.Text == "Console")
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Type of Console:" + consoleTextBox.Text, new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(50, 433));
        }

        if (comboBox3.Visible == true) //iphone selection box is visible then show selected model on print document
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Type of Phone:" + comboBox3.Text, new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(50, 433));


        e.Graphics.DrawString("Service Type:" + serviceDesc.Text, new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(50, 463));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Description:" + description4Repair.Text, new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(50, 493));
```

```

Comment: You need to wrap your text as explained in [Drawstring word wrap or display entire text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507842/drawstring-word-wrap-or-display-entire-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the overload of [`DrawString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to layout the text within a given rectangle. To determine the size of the rectangle use [`MeasureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring(v=vs.110).aspx). Keep track of the vertical location in an extra variable. Your code would look like this:

```
private int DrawWrapped(string text, Font f, Point location, Size maxSize, Graphics g)
{
    // how much space is needed
    var neededRect = g.MeasureString(text, f, maxSize.Width - location.X);
    var rect = new Rectangle(location, neededRect.ToSize());
    g.DrawString(text, f, Brushes.Black, rect, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    return (int) Math.Ceiling(neededRect.Height);
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int y = 373; // keep track of where we are on the page vertically
    using (var arial14 = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular))
    {
        // add the used height to where we are
        y += DrawWrapped("DEVICE INFORMATION:", arial14, new Point(286, y), e.PageBounds.Size, e.Graphics);
        y += (2 * arial14.Height); // add some white space
    }
    using (var arial15 = new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular))
    {
        y += DrawWrapped("Device Type:" + devices.Text, arial15, new Point(50, y), e.PageBounds.Size, e.Graphics);

        if (devices.Visible == true && devices.Text == "Console") // better use && me thinks 
        {
            y += DrawWrapped("Type of Console:" + consoleTextBox.Text, arial15, new Point(50, y ), e.PageBounds.Size, e.Graphics);
        }
        if (comboBox3.Visible == true) //iphone selection box is visible then show selected model on print document
        {
            y += DrawWrapped("Type of Phone:" + comboBox3.Text, arial15, new Point(50, y ), e.PageBounds.Size, e.Graphics);
            y += DrawWrapped("Service Type:" + serviceDesc.Text, arial15,  new Point(50, y ), e.PageBounds.Size, e.Graphics);
            y += DrawWrapped("Description:" + description4Repair.Text, arial15, new Point(50, y), e.PageBounds.Size, e.Graphics);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the result will look like:

[image: printed wrapped]