# How can I write overflowed text to the next line in picturebox?

Tags: c#, text, overflow, paint, picturebox

I am painting to PictureBox but the problem is my painting (text) overflow from picture box. How can I write to the next line?

```
    private string idbul(string gelenid)
    {
        string id = gelenid;
        string[] malzeme = id.Split(' ');
        string mal_id = malzeme[0];
        mal_id = mal_id.Replace(" ", "");
        return mal_id;
    }
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 8))
        {
            string id = idbul(comboBox1.Text);
            string tanim = tanimbul(comboBox1.Text);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string tarih = now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            e.Graphics.DrawString("SKYLAB TEKNOLOJİ", myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(2, 145));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("ÜRÜN KODU: " + id, myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(2, 160));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Tanım : " + tanim, myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(2, 175));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Tarih : "+tarih, myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(2, 190));

        }
    }
    private string tanimbul(string p)
    {
        string id = p;
        string[] malzeme = id.Split(' ');
        malzeme[0] = "";
        string mal_id = String.Join(" ", malzeme);
        return mal_id;
    }
```

The string variable "tanim" can be long text so it is overflowing. From the screenshot, you can see the problem.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what are `idbul()` and `tanimbul()`. can you be more specific what do you mean by overflow from the picture box

Comment: give me **403 Forbidden**

Comment: now http://i63.tinypic.com/117g3n7.jpg

Comment: reduce the font size

Comment: but it can still overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DrawString you can specify the bounding rectangle (kind of like margins) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507842/drawstring-word-wrap-or-display-entire-text)

edit* I looked into it more, the word wrapping only happens for actual words, as in it won't wrap in the middle of a word, only at the end of a word and before the start of the next word.

You can also try getting the length of the tanim (tanim.Length) and writing a separate DrawString if its longer than what will fit into your box.

something like this:

```
if(tanim.Length>x)
{
    drawstring("tanim : "+tanim.substring(0,x),font,brush,firstlinestart);
    drawstring(tanim.substring(x),font,brush,secondlinestart);
}
```

where x is the number of characters you can have fit onto the first line.

Comment: just a reminder: if the text is too big it will overlap to the next line

Comment: that's what they want isn't it? The text is going outside of the bounds of his picturebox to the right side, and they said "how can I write to the next line?". If you specify the bounding rectangle for drawstring, it'll wrap it automatically. Only problem then is knowing if it wrapped, and to adjust the position of the next line of text.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a dummy label with visible = false`;

2. use the function to resize the font

   ```
   private float scaleFont(Label lab, string txt)
   {
       lab.Text = txt;
       var width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(lab.Text, lab.Font).Width;

       while (this.Bounds.Width < width)
       {
           using (var font = new Font(lab.Font.FontFamily, lab.Font.Size - 0.5f, lab.Font.Style))
           {

               lab.Font = font;
               width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(lab.Text, font).Width;
           }              

       }

       return lab.Font.Size;

   }
   ```
3. use it like so

   String drawString = "your string here";
    var fontSize = scaleFont(label1, drawString);
    using(Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", fontSize ))
    {
     //rest of your code
    }